# Difference between "nandroid" and "nandroid + ext"

Tags: backup, nandroid

I own a CM9 Motorola Backflip MB300. I'm planning downgrading it and reapplying the stock ROM. To prevent rendering it unusable, I'm going to perform a nandroid backup, but I get two options: "backup" and "backup + ext".

What is the difference?

[image]

Comment: Just a raw guess: Some ROMs use a special partition for App2SD+, called "sd-ext". Most don't. So I often saw errors like `skipping sd-ext`, or something with "not found". Might be they "outsourced" that from the usual Nandroid backup to avoid irritation with that error.